# Comparing two distributions of R² values of regression models built using bootsrapped subsets of data?

Tags: variance, mean, bootstrap, r-squared

Added more details to an earlier (now deleted) post.
About whuber's earlier suggestions to look at questions about variable selection: I tried looking on the forum regarding similar issues but I am unable to find the right/relevant topic. Perhaps I am unable to really pinpoint the issue. I don't know.

In one experiment, I built several regression models by generating several samples (around 2000) from my data, I suppose something on the lines of bootstrap samples. The regression models were built with four independent variables, say x1, x2, x3 and x4. The model is a log-log model. This form of the model is used frequently in related studies. I back-transformed the predicted values and computed the R² and RMSE values.

In the second experiment, two of the independent variables, x1 and x2 were computed with modified equations and the processes were repeated i.e. several models and corresponding R² and RMSE values were computed. For clarity, the independent variables were x1a, x2a, x3, x4. (In other words, x1a and x2a were appended to the data and in each iteration, a model was built with x1, x2, x3, x4 and x1a, x2a, x3,x4 followed by calculation of respective R² and RMSE values)

Now, I am trying to figure out how to compare two groups of R² and RMSE values. I am trying to show that the changes in the independent variables are responsible for differences in the two groups if any. There are no changes in the other two independent variables whatsoever.

I looked at the boxplots of the two groups. The differences in two groups of R² and RMSE values are apparent in the spreads and median values. How do I quantify these difference? Can I use the F test to show they are different? Or other tests that are robust to normality assumptions?

Basically, the aim of my experiments is to say that the changes to the independent variables can improve R² values and reduce the RMS errors (by reducing the spread and improving medians as shown in the image)

[image: Two distributions of R²]

I hope this is sufficient to identify some key points that I could consider from here on. Thank you!

Comment: In the future, when you want to improve an unanswered post, please do not delete it: edit it instead.  See our [help] for more about how this site works.  Here is how you can search for relevant posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=variable%20selection.